# Organic reactions in alien peat

Tags: aliens, chemistry, life, organic

So imagine there's a peat composed of a mixture of partially decomposed polypropylene and polyethylene. Another girl and I worked out the reactions for polyethylene and its decomposition byproducts, but I am stuck on the reactions for polypropylene.

Specifically, I am stuck on the products and intermediates of anaerobic oxidation of propylene glycol. I have looked at papers and read that it can be oxidized to hydroxyacetone, acetic acid and methylglyoxal in the presence of catalysts. I believe you could further hydrate hydroxyacetone to get glycerol and break it down into acrolein and acrylic acid.

There is a lot of energy in the environment - pressures are high (its underground after all) and temperatures can reach over 100 degrees Celsius, possibly as high as 200 degrees. This is because the decomposition of polypropylene and polyethylene generates a lot of heat, likewise with anaerobic oxidation.

I'm not sure you'll get propionaldehyde and or acetone as a result of reactions with propylene glycol - it seems like dehydration reactions would not happen here due to the moistness of the environment (it is compressed peat).

It seems like methane should also be anaerobically oxidized to form methanol and formaldehyde. So at the bottom of gas pockets, there should be pools of methanol, and formaldehyde, along with a mixture distributed within the peat composed of propanol and in lesser amounts, ethanol, ethylene glycol, and propylene glycol. Furthermore, there are traces of ethyl acetate and propyl acetate, as well as other alcohols and esters. The acetates and glycols can transesterify to produce highly flammable esters.

Perhaps there are other reactions I missed - the natural gas pockets should also contain large quantities of propane and carbon dioxide. There should be smaller quantities of ethylene and propylene within the gas.

There will be deposits of soap forming from the anaerobic decomposition of ethylene glycol and propylene glycol. I figure the peat will smell like earthy, sweet pear wine, possibly also pungent if there's formaldehyde around.

EDIT: For clarity, I just need help with the aforementioned reactions that I'm stuck on - I don't know what intermediates and byproducts they end up having and or if the reactions exist at all under the conditions that I've given

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: We'd need temperature, pressure, gas/other composition. We'd also need to know your objectives as we don't exist just to provide lists of chemicals - what do you want to be there and for what purpose specifically and then we can tell you how to get there - else the question is likely to be closed as too broad.

Comment: This is a chemistry question.

Answer (score 1):

**Propylene glycol is fermented to acetate and other short chain fatty acids.  But also a lot of sulfur compounds!**

Fermentation is a term for anaerobic oxidation.  Fermentation goes on in cow rumens.  Propylene glycol apparently can help cows under certain ciircumstances.  Mostly the byproducts of fermentation are short chain fatty acids:  acetate, propionate, butyrate, etc.

But sometimes anaerobic oxidation uses sulfur as the oxidizing agent.  These products are smelly.

[Ruminal Fermentation of Propylene Glycol and Glycerol](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/jf071076i)

[image: sulfur products]

In this project (and I am not sure how to use this sort of info for a worldbuilding project) you could have smelly sulfur compounds present.  Not that butyrate is especially sweet smelling!

Comment: Thank you! This is very interesting. Mainly the utility of this info is what kind of compounds I could expect to get in some hypothetical oil refinery situation that might arise with the wealth of chemicals this peat brings.

Comment: I get it.  An ancient deposit of plastic for people to mine in the distant future.  Maybe the fatty acids combine into a cheeselike substance that your future characters immoderately gorge upon?

Comment: Nah, it's more likely to end up as soap.